# Calculating carried over earnings - python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, finance

I am building an earnings tracker. The sites I do work for all have a minimum you need to hit to be able to get paid, if you dont hit it then the earnings are carried over to the following week.

All the data is going to be stored in a sqlite database, with earnings paired to their earned date, the point that I cant get my head around is how to carry forward earnings that dont meet the payout minimum.

For example:
site 1: Payments: weekly, Minimum payout $500
Earnings on site 1:
week 1: $200
week 2: $100
week 3: $200

I want the fetched data to tell me what I currently have ready to be paid out, so for week 1 and 2 it should be 0 and then week 3 should show $500.

I also need to add in a time delta of 21 days to account for the payment hold, pretty sure I can work that out though.

Not 100% sure I did a great job at explaining it, hopefully it's enough to be able to understand the problem that I am trying to solve.

The only way I can think of solving this would be having an "unpaid" column that rests to 0 everytime the payout amount is hit, but then it causes issues with having to work with the 21 day hold as far as I can see since I want the data to show whats due to be paid that week so anything within the last 21 days would have to be removed from the unpaid calculation. (thinking out loud right now, since I am not able to sit and code this out at the minute to test it).If it was just the 21 day hold or fixed weekly payment schedule I could work this out but the 2 of them together throws me off since I'm not sure which one to start with.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you show what you've done so far in terms of actual code, even if it is not fully working.

Comment: The question wasn't really a code based question it was more the overall logic that I needed to understand to make it work. Managed to work it out using ChatGPT to fill in the blanks in my knowledge on what I was missing to get it working though.